# Worms Armageddon lags during game play on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, worms-armageddon

Worms Armageddon is installed and all menu options work except the drop bars, they are blank (*not including during gameplay*)

****The worst is during game play, it lags so bad it is impossible to play.**** (*does not lag in menu before a match*)

I have tryed the other technique posted for other problems on here (*other than installing an earlier windows version*) but there has to be a way.

I need the wisdome of the WWW to set me on the path to enlightenment. please help :)

Comment: What are your computer specs?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are using the [latest update](http://wa.team17.com/main.html?page=supp&area=upda&file=15).

Try selecting a different graphics API from the advanced options screen.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running Worms in compatibility mode:

1. right click on the icon
2. select "properties"
3. select the "compatibility" tab
4. you should be running Worms for compatibility with Windows 98 -
   Windows XP

I have had problems with Worms 2 and Worms World Party, as they are made for earlier operating systems and do not run by themselves on windows 7/8.